# Display different output on secondary monitor

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am creating simple application for altering an image projected by projector. 
I would like that projected image to be different than the desktop.
Consider simple example. My application would take a print-screen and add some bitmap to it. Than it will displayed on the projector. While original image on notebook monitor is the same, the projected image will contain this added bitmap.

I am using GDI for altering image the image in C++/CLI, and Windows Forms.

Answer (score 2):

You just create two windows, and position one such that it's on the secondary display, and one such that it's on the primary display. There's nothing "magical" about the second monitor you have to mess with.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to what Billy said, and provide information that you should use `Screens` collection for that.  It will give you exact coordinates of each screen that is available on the system.

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx